# FHIR Page number support

Tags: hl7-fhir

Foe search interactions, while there is support for specifying the number of items expected in the response using the _count parameter, we are not able to find any reference to a parameter to specify the page number. 
The _query parameter can be used for custom queries, but is that an option or is there a better alternative.

For example, what is the standard way to request for the second page of a patient resultset with each page having 10 records? -

GET Patient?_count=10&[pagenumber?]=2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no mechanism to navigate to a specific page.  You use the URLs provided in Bundle.link (e.g. previous, next, first, last) to navigate through the search result set.

Comment: Thanks Lloyd, but I think the same question is applicable for constructing the next/previous/last links as well because they too need some count/page number indications. There seem to be a lot of differences in the reference implementations, like HAPI uses "_getpagesoffset", while spark uses "start" for this purpose. Is it left to individual implementors to define?

Comment: yes, left to the implementers. you have to step through the pages to get the link for the page

Comment: [Vonk](https://simplifier.net/vonk), the successor to Spark, has chosen to implement this with an _skip parameter, so you could do a GET Patient?_count=10&_skip=10

Comment: _skip is not a standard parameter - you can't count on it being supported on all (or even most) servers.  FHIR isn't designed to allow navigation to arbitrary points in a result-set

Comment: Right. But I agree with RahulB "comment" (date june 21 2017) ..  the "previous" "next" "first" and "last" you still need an actual url-value (as seen here) https://www.hl7.org/fhir/http.html#paging  find "This example shows the third page of a search result:"     One example from the HL7 link :   <link>
    <relation value="next"/>
    <url value="http://example.org/Patient?name=peter&stateid=23&page=4"/>
  </link>    The HL7 has example has "page=4", but that does not seem to be standard.  Not sure why this is so confusing  :)    its rest-paging.

Comment: @MirjamBaltus  _skip   Yes!  Very "linq'ish"  :)

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now.  The "next" "previous" have placeholders for the URL values, and as long as YOUR server understands those links, then it works.  If your server wanted to implement "_count=100&pagingainteasy=5", (a non standard example)  , then its fine, because that is what you put in the url values for "next" "previous".  Ok.  Now all the comments and this answer make sense.  Took a few minutes to click.  Thanks.